# What is the proper pronounciation of the scientific name of the ground elder / Aegopodium podagraria?

Tags: botany, terminology

A audio sample would be great. As a kind of bonus: I would appreciate a kind of database, which contains a lot of botanical plant names.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is only about language/pronunciation, not biology. Also scientific species names are pronounced very differently around the world. The only "proper" pronunciation would be the original latin/Greek, but then this is a question about those specific languages.

Comment: @fileunderwater for me it is part of biology when you are able to communicate in a proper way to the community. It's like asking for information around biology, like literatur. And I think the probability that question got be answered, is higher in biology.stack exchange as in english- latin- or oldgreek.stackexchange. proper means for me that somebody can understand, to get a idea how it sounds like. thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b170) is a american database which offers sound samples for a lot of scientific plant names.

Comment: for me the question is now answered. and i will close in 2 days when stackexchange allow me to do. but anyway other sources are still welcome.